# html, javascript, show buttons if variable has a certan value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, variables

I am currently using cookies in my website to try to implement a system where two buttons on the screen will show if a variable has a certain value. I am using cookies to ask the user for their username, and save their username as a cookie. Now what I'm trying to accomplish is to set a variable to the value or the cookie which is the players username. Now that there is a variable which has the value of the username entered, I want to create a statement saying if the variable or the player's username is "hi" for example, show the two buttons. if their username isn't hi, hide the buttons.
This is my current code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
var username;
function checkCookie() {
  var user=getCookie("username");
  if (user != "") {
var username = document.cookie("username";
  } else {
    
     }
  }
}
if var username = "hi" {
   document.getElementById("speedbtn").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("jmpbtn").style.display = "block";
}
else {
 document.getElementById("speedbtn").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("jmpbtn").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="checkCookie()"></body>
<!--The buttons I need to show or hide depending on the usernname-->
   <div style="z-index: 999; position: fixed">
        <button id="speedbtn">Change speed</button>
        <button id="jmpbtn">Change jump power</button>
      </div>
</html>
```

Currently, the code isn't working and the buttons are showing up regardless of what the players username is. I can't figure out where I went wrong in the process. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong and how I can achieve this result?

Comment: There are numerous issues with your code. In trying to troubleshoot I found one of your functions had an extra `}` at the end, you had an `if` statement without `()` and 3 or 4 other issues. You can easily step through these yourself. Load your HTML page into Chrome and open development tools (inspector). Look at the console. Fix your errors then come back if you still need help.

Comment: console.log the username and check what value is coming?

Comment: Other issue is that your script is on the head, so its executing before the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first step you can make a try like this that is error free:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var username = "";

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
function checkCookie() {
  var user=getCookie("username");
  if (user != "") {
    username = document.cookie("username");
  } else {
    
  }

  if (username == "hi") {
    document.getElementById("speedbtn").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("jmpbtn").style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
   document.getElementById("speedbtn").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("jmpbtn").style.display = "none";
  }

}

window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  checkCookie();
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--The buttons I need to show or hide depending on the usernname-->
   <div style="z-index: 999; position: fixed">
        <button id="speedbtn">Change speed</button>
        <button id="jmpbtn">Change jump power</button>
      </div>
</body>      
</html>
```

`if(username = "hi")` will always get true.

Comment: I tried running it with the suggestions in the console and I got an error with the .style.display part of the code. Any default styling required?

Comment: @Bob As I commented on the question, your script is on the head, so its executing before the body exists. Move the script tag to the bottom of body

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Bob, if it solved your problem, please don't forget to mark this as answer...